# How to get the total disc space occupied by the list of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have about 1000 very large files (each more than 5 GB). These files have either .bam .cram, .fastq.gz, .fq extensions (which I do not know). I just have these lists, for example,

list.txt:

```
A-ADC-AD000856
A-ADC-AD000884
A-ADC-AD000910
A-ADC-AD000937
A-ADC-AD000946
```

and they could be have other file formats as well:

```
A-ADC-AD000856.bam
A-ADC-AD000856.gvcf.gz
A-ADC-AD000856.vcf
A-ADC-AD000884.cram
A-ADC-AD000884.vcf
A-ADC-AD000910.bam
A-ADC-AD000910.g.vcf
A-ADC-AD000937.fq
A-ADC-AD000946.fastq.gz
A-ADC-AD000946.vcf
```

I was trying `locate` with something like this below, but is there a better approach and get the total size of these files in GB?

```
TotalSize={}
for line in `cat list.txt`; do
GetFile="$(locate $line | egrep "bam|cram|fastq|fastq.gz|fq.gz|fq")"
size="$(wc -c $GetFile)"
TotalSize=$(($size+$TotalSize))
done
```

Comment: Where are the files? Are they all in the same directory, or scattered all over the filesystem, or something in between?

Comment: @GordonDavisson No, they are in different directories. Don't know the exact location.

Comment: `stat` or `du` would be faster than `wc -c`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
for line in `cat list.txt`; do
# echo "Doing file: $line"
GetFile="$(locate $line | egrep 'bam|cram|fastq|fastq.gz|fq.gz|fq')"
size="$(du -ch $GetFile | tail -1 | cut -f 1)"
echo "$GetFile,$size" >> "/total_files.txt"
done
```

Then I can sum the value on spreadsheet.

Comment: Use `stat --printf "%n,%s\n" "$GetFile"` instead of `du -ch $GetFile | tail -1 | cut -f 1` ... and directly redirect that to "/total_files.txt" ...